# rsync local root to remote server with non root preserve user:group it's possible

Tags: file-permissions, rsync, file-ownership

I'm writing code for create a backup rsync based.

On server a run code how root, and send with rsync some question about system, and all users accounts.

On backup server put content (via rsync) on one user account (user)

Try -azhEX --numeric-ids and -azh, y others.. but in any case I can keep the user and group id for when making a restore.

It's possible with rsync on this scenario, restore with original user:group ?

I run on both sides latest version 3.1.1 of rsync.

Answer (score 0):

rsync alone cannot do this.

A very close solution to your problem is `rdiff-backup` which uses librsync internally and stores the user permissions and other meta-data in a separate directory.

http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/

Comment: Thanks. rdiff-backup need on both sides rdiff-backup and very old system with some know bugs on librsync and others, and it's not my scenario. Prefer create a internal system for own metadata and after restore correct owner and group.